# Parsing basic JSON with IOS

Tags: php, ios, json

my JSON string looks like this:

> {"msg":"The email: ddhaxor97@gmail.com doesn't exist, cannot retrieve
>   data","code":120}

My parsing code looks like this

```
NSData *data= [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"Json array = %@", jsonArray);
```

How do I get the values out of JSON Array, if I print JSON array (i.e. the last line) I get this:

> Json array = {
>       code = 120;
>       msg = "The email: ddxxx@gmail.com doesn't exist, cannot retrieve data"; }

If I try using `[jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]` then it fails. So why can't I access it?

my php looks like this to generate the string:

```
return json_encode(array("msg" => $msg, "code" => $code));
```

I am totally stuck on it, all the examples show me how to parse a dictionary but not a little array like this. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because "arrays" in JSON are actually "dictionaries" in iOS. Try using:

```
NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
[dict objectForKey:"code"];
```